# Query for a distinct list of records using the 'NOT BETWEEN' constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to construct a query that gives me a list of distinct records after applying a 'NOT BETWEEN' constraint on date fields in another table.

Given the following...

```
User Table:
magicID    name
100        Greg
200        Fred

Event Table:
magicID    date
100        2011-02-24
100        2011-02-23
100        2011-02-22
200        2011-02-22
```

How can I get a list of distinct users that don't fall within a certain date range? I want this to be **very** explicit. If I'm looking for users that don't have event records between 2011-02-23 and 2011-02-24, I'd would expect to get one result back,

```
200    Fred
```

That's the goal. But the below query give me all users. I want that 'NOT BETWEEN' constraint to be explicit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* FROM users, events WHERE events.date NOT BETWEEN '2011-02-23' AND '2011-02-24'
```

This query returns all users...

```
100    Greg
200    Fred
```

I'm missing something very fundamental...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Because the values being compared will not be NULL, in MySQL the best performing option is the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/):

```
   SELECT u.magicid,
          u.name
     FROM USER u
LEFT JOIN EVENT e ON e.magicid = u.magicid
                 AND e.date BETWEEN '2011-02-23' AND '2011-02-24'
    WHERE e.magicid IS NULL
```

[If the columns are nullable, NOT EXISTS is the better choice](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/):

```
SELECT u.magicid,
       u.name
  FROM USER u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM EVENT e
                    WHERE e.magicid = u.magicid
                      AND e.date BETWEEN '2011-02-23' AND '2011-02-24')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ...
From users
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From events As E1
                    Where E1.magicid = users.magicid
                        And E1.date Between '2011-02-03' And '2011-02-24'
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't joining your tables at all.  You shoudl be able to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM users, events 
WHERE user.magicID = events.magicID
and events.date NOT BETWEEN '2011-02-23' AND '2011-02-24'
```

Comment: I had tried this with no luck. In fact, the example I wrote in the original question should have been this. It still returns the user presumably since there is an event outside the range.

Comment: In that case, @OMG Ponies is the direction to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM users LEFT JOIN events ON user.magicID = events.magicID 
WHERE events.date NOT BETWEEN '2011-02-23' AND '2011-02-24'